# Save word document as html with inline css

Tags: c#, html, converters, inline, docx

I want to save a docx document as html using microsoft word built in function, but generate it with inline css instead of the generated style tags. Does anyone know if its possible?

Just to note, i want to use word's built in function of save as and not use an external libary

Thank you very much

Comment: I literally Googled "save word document as html" and Google told me the solution. That is, if I'm understanding your question correctly.

Comment: But it generates style tags instead of inline css. I need inline css, not style tag and classes

Answer (score 2):

File=>Options => Advanced => General => Web Options
here check rely on css option to generate inline css.
Note: I'm Using MS WORD 2010

Comment: Thank you very much for your response. I'll check it out in the office tomorrow. The thing is, im actually doing it programaticly (its sort of a word plugin) but if its available  from the gui, i guess i can do it from the api

Comment: ya. If they have it in their core then its should be accessible to anywhere, either via gui or via api.

Comment: Ive just tried it but it still doesnt generate inline css. It creates style tags and font definitions and than puts it in the document

Comment: Sorry, I don't know much about this. I can't help more. sorry for that.